# HTML table reduces the print font size on entire page

Tags: html, css, printing

I had a page that displayed some text and a centered table below that text. I added another table adjacent to the first table. The font size remained the same on screen, but in print the font size got reduced.

This is probably so that two tables could fit one besides another. Problem is in the fact that font size got reduced on the entire page, even outside the tables (which is undesired). Does anyone know the cause for this behavior, and how can I keep the declared font size outside the tables (it is explicitly declared but in print it has no effect).

Comment: Does this occur in all browsers or just one? if so, which browsers are you seeing this in and are you printing at 100% or scale-to-fit?

Comment: It occurs in Ff and Chrome, but not in IE. I am printing at 100%

Comment: Ah, it seems that font size did not decrease but the whole page was scaled to fit the paper size. So explicitly setting the outer text to larger size couldn't help, but setting the table text to smaller size helped by reducing the page width hence no need for scaling.

Comment: so... are you good? or is there still an issue to solve?

Comment: Well, the page now prints as it should be. Thanks for your help. Is there anything I should do now (somehow mark the question or something)?

Comment: You answered your own question.  You should post the solution as an answer (below) and then accept it.  I believe you can accept your own answer after 24 hours.  You won't get the rep points but the question will be marked as answered and accepted, for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Original answer by user [@celicni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/239434/celicni)

It seems that font size did not decrease but the whole page was scaled to fit the paper size. So explicitly setting the outer text to larger size couldn't help, but setting the table text to smaller size helped by reducing the page width hence no need for scaling.